# Custom Base repository function not found

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data

I have generic base repository defined as follows:

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface IBaseRepository<Template extends BaseModel, Id > extends 
                            ElasticsearchRepository<Template,Id>, ICustomRepository{
}
```

My ICustomRepository repository interface is defined as follows:

```
@Repository
public interface ICustomRepository {
      void someCustomFunction();

}

public class CustomRepositoryImpl implements ICustomRepository{
    @Override
    void someCustomFunction(){
    }
}
```

Now when I use the baserepository as:

```
@Repository
public interface OrderRepository extends BaseRepository<OrderModel,Long>{
}
```

when I Autowired OrdeRepository in my service class it gives me compile error:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
> Error creating bean with name 'OrderRepository ' defined in
> abc.example.OrderRepository defined in
> @EnableElasticsearchRepositories declared on ElkApplication:
> Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No
> property someCustomFunction found for type OrderModel!

Can someone please suggest whats going wrong here and how to resolve this?

Comment: "My ICustomRepository repository interface is defined as follows" but you have CustomRepository interface. And what is your BaseRepository class, you're not showing? Can you please fix the example to be runnable.

Comment: your someCustomFunction is implemented in CustomRepositoryImpl, which you are not using. so isn't the error message correct?

Comment: @eis when i do
interface OrderRepository extends BaseRepository<OrderModel,Long>, I am expecting to get functionalities of both ElasticRepository and my ICustomRepository.
In case of ElasticRepository, my understanding is that JDK proxy instance is created programmatically using Spring's ProxyFactory API to back the interface and a MethodInterceptor intercepts all calls to the instance and routes the method into the appropriate places. I am wanted to add an additional custom functionality by means of ICustomRepository, that way all derived repositories (OrderRepository in this case) use it.

Comment: You should not add someCustomFunction in the base repository, even if you would like to have then you have to either implement that method using the default keyboard in the base interface or implement this in the repository that's extending the base repository.

Comment: @sonus21 if I have a   "class OrderRepostory implements IBaseRespository" instead of "interface OrderRepository extends IBaseRepository" I lose on the springs' JDK proxy feature and will also have to implement functions like findByOrderId, findByOrderLocation etc (Functions of OrderRepository which are Derived Query Methods ) which were auto proxied when declared as interface. I wanted to avoid this path because of  the above mentioned reason.

Comment: @JudeAloysius well you will not lose JDK proxy if you define method public.

Comment: @sonus21 can you please share an example or link which describes this.

Comment: did you try that and check if JDK is proxy is working or not? You should start with the default method and verify.

Comment: @sonus21 yes default interface approach did work. Thanks!

Comment: @sonus21 one challenge i am facing in default methods of interface is that i am not able to inject EntityManager which is required in "someCustomFucntion". is there any other way to acquire the object of EntityManager

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting comment to answer

ICustomRepo

```
@Repository
public interface ICustomRepository {
      void someCustomFunction();

}
```

IBaseRepository

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface IBaseRepository<Template extends BaseModel, Id > extends 
                            ElasticsearchRepository<Template,Id>, ICustomRepository{
}
```

OrderRepository

```
@Repository
public interface OrderRepository extends IBaseRepository<OrderModel,Long>{
}
```

OrderRepository is a repository interface and a bean is created by a spring bean processor but this `OrderRepository` does not implement `someCustomFunction` and even spring has no idea about its implementation except it knows it has been implemented by `CustomRepositoryImpl` so at bootstrap/startup spring throws an error.

So instead of just having the definition of `someCustomFunction` we need to implement this in `ICustomRepository`, thanks to Java 8 we can implement the method in the interface as well

```
@Repository
public interface ICustomRepository {
     default void someCustomFunction() {
        // some code here
     }
}
```

This code will be working fine, JDK and other proxies will work on this method as well, also we can apply AOP  on `someCustomFunction`.

It is also possible to override this method in any repository given that's also using the `default` and `@Override`.

```
@Repository
public interface OrderRepository extends IBaseRepository<OrderModel,Long>{

   @Override
   default void someCustomFunction() {
        // some code here
   }
}
```

Comment: one challenge i am facing in default methods of interface is that i am not able to inject EntityManager which is required in "someCustomFucntion". is there any other way to acquire the object of EntityManager

Comment: You can add the `@Autowired` annotation to the method,method can take EntityManager as parameter did you try that?